# Theme.MaterialComponents not found build Flutter Android app

Tags: android, flutter

hi developer im trying to compile my flutter app for android but i'm getting this error, and i can't fix it?

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> > Android resource linking failed
> > ERROR:AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.MeterialComponents (aka it.leonardoappitalia.cimipro:style/Theme.MeterialComponents) not
> > found.
> > error: resource style/Theme.MeterialComponents (aka it.leonardoappitalia.cimipro:style/Theme.MeterialComponents) not
> > found.
> > error: failed linking references.

main.dart file:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Stripe.publishableKey = stripePublicKey;
  //Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'any string works';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('it')],
      title: 'CiMiPro',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'CiMiPro'),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/logIn': (context) => const LoginSignupScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: material or meterial?, try to check if you are passing correct values and attributes in it. it seems something is miss configured in that file

Comment: can you provide main.dart file

Comment: add a main.dart file

Comment: Are you writing native code in the flutter project(Java code)? If so then the error might be on the native side. Please clarify

Comment: Stupid typo in the styles.xml file I typed Meterial instead of Material